# DB Table Design - Different Statuses for Mail Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, constraints

I am making a database for Mail and design of the `MAIL` table is as follows:

```
ID (Surrogate PK)

Recipient/Sender (Coming as FK from `REGISTERED_USERS` table - Recipient if outgoing mail and Sender if incoming mail)

Dispatch/Receive Date

Status (Coming as FK)

PostType (Whether it is Sent or Received mail)
```

**Issue**

My issue is in the **Status** column as statuses are different for Outgoing or Incoming mail (e.g. Received for incoming and Ordered, Stamped, Dispatched, etc. for outgoing mail).

**My Approach**

I have tried a *trigger* to implement this, but I want to ensure that is there any better solution/design for it using some Constraints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question? You want to `check` the status or what?

Comment: @juergend Thanks! I want to ensure that only allowed statuses go for respective type of mail (Incoming/Outgoing)

Comment: You can use the `check` keyword which makes it possible to define rules.

Comment: There's not really much you can do with a single table approach.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks! I have tried to make two separate tables for `INCOMING` and `OUTGOING` mail, so should I go with that? Which would be the better approach?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your entire implementation really. I mean, you could use a `CHECK` constraint, but that feels a bit hacky to me here.

Comment: @DavidG I am skeptical about that approach as well - design of both INCOMING and OUTGOING was same (and there was different FK table (of MAIL_STATUS) as well)

Comment: It's verry hard to say what would be the best approach without IN/Out data , the design is the refer to the shcema you make with the details of incoming/outgoing data.

Comment: You should not have two tables, but you should have separate columns for incoming and outgoing info. If needed you can add 3rd computed column that will show combined statuses.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic So its ok (from a design perspective - not a design expert) to have incoming column NULL for an outgoing mail and vice-versa?

Comment: Depends on whether both types of Statuses will have the same attributes. If yes, you can store both types in one table if you distinguish them by adding StatusType attribute.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Yes attributes are exactly same - just values are different! Thanks.

Comment: If the table for `Mail_Status` values had a `Post_Type` column then you could easily check that the status for a given message is valid for its `Post_Type`. There could conceivably be status values that appear twice, e.g. "In Transit" might be valid for both inbound and outbound messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be an opinion based but..

You should not store different data in same column. You should split all those incoming/outgoing columns into two and fill only relevant ones for different type of mail

In your solution, if you have **John** in `Recipient/Sender` column, you don't know whatever John is recipient or sender until you check the `PostType` column and that's not really good design. Each column should be self-identifying.

I would suggest changing your design to:

```
ID
Sender 
Recipient
DispatchDate
ReceiveDate
IncomingStatus
OutgoingStatus
PostType
```

And if you really need combined data to show somewhere, you can create a view for that purpose as:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN PostType = 1 THEN Sender ELSE Recipient END AS [Recipient/Sender] 
   CASE WHEN PostType = 1 THEN DispatchDate ELSE ReceiveDate END AS [Dispatch/Receive Date]
```

etc..

(or add them as computed columns)

Also by separating columns, you make yourself a room to maybe also store recipients for outgoing mails for example, if that need arise in the future.

Comment: THAT!! I think I got the best design. +1 and Thanks!!

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Yes, this design is surely better, attributes with duplicate meaning are bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can store both Status types in one table if both types have exactly the same attributes and you distinguish them by adding a StatusType attribute or something similar.

If attributes of OutgoingStatus are different from the attributes of IncomingStatus then you should consider creating two separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to implement a CHECK constraint on your Mail table.

You could add a CHECK constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Mail
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MAILSTATUS 
CHECK ((PostType = 'Outgoing' AND [Status] IN('Ordered', 'Stamped', 'Dispatched')) OR (PostType = 'Incoming' AND [Status] IN('Received')))
```

Afterwards you will not be allowed to insert records into your Mail table that does not meet the criteria of the CHECK constraint. If you try to do so, you will will an error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_MAILSTATUS". The conflict occurred in database "YourDatabase", table "dbo.Mail".